# JSP Video Streaming (with Servlet)

Tags: java, jsp, video

I am using @BalusC image servlet http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html to serve images on my website. Turns out that this servlet is generic, so it ends up serving documents (like PDF files) as well, however it doesn't seem to be working very well for videos. I'm currently using http://videojs.com as library to reproduce videos.

I have two websites, one hosts uploaded files on Amazon S3 and the other hosts the files locally. The video stream works fine when the files are hosted on S3 (without servlet, you simply point the video url for video.js)

However, when trying to stream files stored locally (therefore needing a servlet) the video simply won't reproduce.

Questions:

1) Is it acceptable to create a servlet to stream videos?

2) If yes to 1, why isn't the servlet streaming the video?

3) If no to 1, how could I stream a video using JSP/Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of media players require that the server supports the so-called HTTP range requests. I.e. it must be able to return a specific byte range of the media file on request with a [`Range`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header. For example, only the bytes at exactly the index 1000 until with 2000 on a file of 10MB long. This is mandatory for many media players in order to be able to skip a certain range of the media stream quickly enough and/or to improve buffering speed by creating multiple connections which each requests different parts of the file.

This is however a lot of additional code in the servlet which requires a well understanding of the HTTP `Range` specification. A ready to use example is provided in flavor of this [file servlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) by the very same author of the image servlet which you found.

Note that the container's builtin default servlet usually also supports this. So if you have the chance, you could also just put the media file straight in the webapp itself, or to add the folder with the media files as a new webapp context to the server configuration, so that it's directly available by URL without the need for a homegrown servlet.

Comment: works flawlessly. Images and Files are served normally, videos (even 720p) are streamed normally. Thanks for response!